# Play framework 2.5.0 Websockets example

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.5

Play framework 2.5.0 Websockets example.

in play 2.5.0 websockets code is changed to support akka streams but I'm not able find a sample code to use it.

Comment: There are example projects at https://github.com/playframework/play-websocket-scala and https://github.com/playframework/play-websocket-java now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be properly documented in 2.5.1 as you can see here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5057

---

In the meantime you can take a look at the Migration Guide which has a part on Streams:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25#Migrating-WebSockets-%28WebSocket%29

You will notice that the important part is the `WebSocket.MappedWebSocketAcceptor<In,Out>` class. You use this one to tell Play how to convert `Message` frames to your own types - like `String`, `Json`, etc.

Fortunately the Java API of Play provides some predefined implementations. Let's say you want to handle WebSocket connections which exchange JSON data. Then you would use `WebSocket.Json` (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/WebSocket.java#L71)

```
return WebSocket.Json.accept(requestHeader -> {
  // returns a Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, ?>
})
```

Comment: There are example projects at https://github.com/playframework/play-websocket-scala and https://github.com/playframework/play-websocket-java

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and then eventually update my answer