# Play 2.5 ActorFlow: cannot convert from Flow<String,String,capture#1-of ?> to Flow<String,String,?>

Tags: java, playframework, akka-stream, playframework-2.5, type-mismatch

While migrating to Play 2.5 I'm trying to implement new WebSocket functionality as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets)(Handling WebSockets with actors). In Play 2.5.4 there's no play.libs.streams.ActorFlow (as shown in the example), but only play.api.libs.streams.ActorFlow. But when I write this code:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private final Materializer materializer;

    @Inject
    public MyController(ActorSystem actorSystem, Materializer materializer) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.materializer = materializer;
    }

    public WebSocket socket() {
        return WebSocket.Text.accept(request ->
                return ActorFlow.<String, String>actorRef(MyWebSocketActor::props, 256, OverflowStrategy.dropHead(),
                    actorSystem, materializer
                )
        );
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Flow`<String,String,capture#1-of ?> to Flow<String,String,?>`

Can someone please explain me how to implement this approach in 2.5? Why I get this mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same issue with Play 2.5.12. The problem seems to be that `ActorFlow` is not yet properly implemented for Java in Play 2.5.x. (which is exactly why you had `play.api.libs.streams.ActorFlow` from the Scala side).

The proper Java code seem to be in for Play 2.6.x. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.25/core/play-streams/src/main/java/play/libs/streams/ActorFlow.java

For now, I guess the easy solution is to stick with (the deprecated) `LegacyWebsocket` or migrate to 2.6.x onwards.

Comment: Thanks for the response anyway:) However, I've found the way to utilize new WebSocket implementation in Play 2.5 based on what is written here: http://nuah.livejournal.com/315561.html

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are still using Play 2.5, the `ActorFlow` implementation from version 2.6.25 ([`ActorFlow.java`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.25/core/play-streams/src/main/java/play/libs/streams/ActorFlow.java)) can be copied into your own project and used as is without significant changes (only change the `package` declaration depending on where you place it).

Assuming the class is now available in `utils.ActorFlow`,
the example below allows you to interact with a WebSocket connection using actors, as described in the [WebSockets documentation for Play 2.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-actors).

```
import play.mvc.*;
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import javax.inject.Inject;

// Replace in Play 2.6
import utils.ActorFlow;
//import play.libs.streams.ActorFlow;

public class MyWebSocketController extends Controller {

    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private final Materializer materializer;

    @Inject
    public MyWebSocketController(ActorSystem actorSystem, Materializer materializer) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.materializer = materializer;
    }

    public WebSocket ws() {
        return WebSocket.Json.accept(requestHeader -> {

            // Note: check Origin header here for extra security

            return ActorFlow.actorRef(
                MyWebSocketActor::props,
                actorSystem,
                materializer
            );
        });
    }
}
```

You may still need to extend the actor from `UntypedActor` instead of `AbstractActor` and implement `onReceive` instead of `createReceive`. Although `AbstractActor` exists in Akka 2.4, it has an experimental API which was subjected to changes in later versions.

```java
import akka.actor.*;

// Note: extends AbstractActor in Play 2.6
public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        out.tell("{\"message\": \"I received your message!\"}", self());
    }


    @Override
    public void postStop() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Play2.5 Java WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167501)